# Waiting for connection from host

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I built Unity project for iOS on Windows. It created xcode project and I run it on macOS to deploy in iOS. After following line is running it waits for 10 seconds.

```
UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics([[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String]);
```

In debug console following lines show up:

```
PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55000
Multi-casting "[IP] xx.xx.xx.xx [Port] 55000 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 2865448700 [EditorId] 3893268416 [Version] 1048832 [Id] iPhonePlayer(iPhone-6s):56000 [Debug] 0 [PackageName] iPhonePlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55000]...
Remaining time:8s
Remaining time:7s
Remaining time:6s
Remaining time:5s
Remaining time:4s
Remaining time:3s
Remaining time:2s
Remaining time:1s
Remaining time:0s
Timed out. Continuing without host connection.
```

Before splash screen appears it is waiting for 10 seconds. How do I stop this connection? This app doesn't have multiplayer or network connection to any server.
Note that I didn't develop this app. My client sent me source codes to run it on iOS.

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this as I was running into the same issue.  It was driving me a little crazy, but I managed to figure out the issue.  It looks like it is coming from Unity's script debugger connection.  If you disable this option in Unity's build settings, this will go away.